# Can't add internal testers in testflight

Tags: ios, iphone, testflight

Okay, so I've uploaded a new app to testflight and succsesfully added one internal tester.

But now, I just can't add more internal testers for my new build (and for old too). First of all I've invited all my testers using "users and roles". They have accepted my invintations. And I've assigned them as my internal testers clicking directly on their e-mails in my users list.

But when I navigate to "my Apps" -> my app -> "test flight" -> "internal testing" my "Add" button is grayed out.

Here is some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

So what have I done wrong, or is it some "internal" testflight bug?

PS. Processing has been finished about 8 hours ago. And I can't even add new testers to my old build where I already have one internal tester.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My corporate laptop is limited to Internet Explorer only. If I use any other browser to access iTunesConnect everything is working fine.

Answer (score 4):

Please note that, you can only add some one as an internal tester,if they have the apple account. They should have apple email address. (no need of developer account)

Edit: You have to add them as team memebers to YOur users and roles section. Then only you can add them as internal testers.

Click on Users and Roles
[image]

Add them to the itunes connect users:

[image]

Comment: I have done this too. But I figured it out. My corporate laptop is limited to Internet Explorer only :) If I use other browser to access iTunesConnect everyting is working fine. Sorry for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to click the Add at least 1 internal tester button and it should come up with a list of all of your users. Or the + symbol next to Internal Testers(0). Then you have to check at least one user and the add button should become available

Comment: That's the problem. After I click "+" and the window with "add" pops up I just can't click that "add" button. It's switched off or something.

Comment: None of your users appear? If anything, you should at least see your name.

Comment: Cant you even click on + sign button ?

Comment: Nope. After granting my second account Admin privileges I've tried to log in with it, but to no success. Even my name is not there.

Guess I will need to contact support in that case.

Comment: @Mr.T I can, but there is just that grayed out "add" button as you can see on my second screenshot.

Comment: Check my answer. @ArseniiNibble